# How to return "this" with different generic type(s) and make it still work for sublcasses?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Take following base class as an example:

```js
abstract class Base<T> {
  public changeGeneric = (): Base<string> => {
    // do something so no matter what "T" currently is it will change to "string"
    return this as Base<string>
  }
}
```

This works as expected. But it gets complicated when extending `Base`:

```js
class Extended<T> extends Base<T> {
   //...
   public additionalFunc = () => {/*...*/}
}

const extended = new Extended<number>();
extended.changeGeneric().additionalFunc(); // this line results in and error
```

After calling `extended.changeGeneric()` the type should be `Extended<string>` but in this case it's (kind of) obviously `Base<string>`. Because `additionalFunc` doesn't exist on type `Base<string>` it throws an error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAQwRgzgLgTiDGUAE8A2IISQIQwUwB4AVAPiQG9gkkAHAVzFQEt4UALEAOwHM8BxPJzwwWSALxIAFAEoAXDnwFoInmTFlK1agHptSAHSGqWmHih0YnJFDZMsGBRELKmq4wF9gn4MDQYsAKIAHlCCACZ4YcRkeCHhWLhO0RTGSLqG+qn0jKIgYWFMUEwA9pwgqABidJysEjLiGtoAVBlN2p7e8KXQSLGhnBFh4khCAO5Iwf2DBJx0ALZgwiQyANzAfeGR+vAcPPyCwiwy+nkFRaXlVTWraXo2dkjMQkimEHSoyK5IXEPCMMUwYBAA)

**Question**

Is it possible to return `this` with different generic type(s) based on the current class the function is executed from? If no, are there workarounds?

This is a really simple example (e.g. `Base` could have more generic types) but I hope it shows the problem.

**More info about actual context**

In my particular case I try to implement a fluent API for form validation. If I really break it down it looks like this:

```js
abstract class BaseConfig<T extends object, Errors = unknown> {
  protected validator: (values: T) => Errors = () => undefined as any;
  constructor(public initalValues: T){}

  public withValidation = <Validator extends (values: T ) => any>(validator: Validator) =>  {
    this.validator = validator ;
    return this as any as BaseConfig<T, ReturnType<Validator>>
  }
}

class SpecialConfig<T extends object, Errors = unknown> extends BaseConfig<T, Errors>{
  protected specialConfigEnabled = false;

  public enableSpecialConfig = () => {
    this.specialConfigEnabled = true;
    return this;
  }
}

interface Coordinate {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const specialConfig = new SpecialConfig<Coordinate>({x: 0, y: 0})
  // should somehow return SpecialConfig<Coordinate, boolean>, but returns BaseConfig<Coordinate, boolean> instead
  .withValidation(({x, y}) => x > y? false : true) 
  // should not be an error
  .enableSpecialConfig();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYQHsA7AMwEsBzAHgBUEcAPCHIgEwwJACsd4AaBAFEoUAlAwBeBAFciAayIEA7kQB8CAN4AoBAgAOo5vBysEAN2DIyrYBDEAuBAAoLyaTjCOaASgQT1wqLifs6+-jJsOOREJghocUQAngDcOkjEkFDS8GJOetIgVrAIZERkEJYAapbungg+GgC+Wmn5hWTFSuUAFtVWNhBkxCFUfda2YvRMLOzOrrVeCGHqwEmqLpbjdlCOYwNiy7rauroQ3WRgAHSuW5NSN-tQCKknCFA4ENJQRAhnF3EYVaJAFYXCEUiUWgCABKHy+RBoiT0OFGm0eqlUaWazS0KDQGAAysjYGRLODyNQ6IxmGwONxeBABIExJIIgplGopjTZtgwPhiBSoUIRCzVMd9IYGbEwMTSchyZRBERQMhYlISJY+alWgUivRlYUcETeHKFRQQk5DuLTucrjKTWSBYqDarTFJoO4Xid3p9vr9bV7sS1SswoBrYDgEIQxKxSrZI+KGI4iNIALYgHBQL2JZNpjNZrQ42AZRD2kmOiHmqQxJQIY3l+VO6jRqCx5XMdYaJMIAAMAhzvca3jSAHoRwgwN0CNJkKYwARUzgp7WffC67KK4KW234wIQAQCKrVqo99JEKvvhhefzK1Rt3HmHuD0fOaVIDhgKw0pcumc9rYhiIJwnC7fshz8dQGAQdREgAfgQDVkD5BBHA9HBfFHcdJ2nWcEEURAMwSegRSgb8WBVI0N0bStLW1IA)

Comment: Could you give more context on what you're trying to achieve? It might help to see if another approach is more suitable for your problem.

Comment: @AlanDarmasaputra thanks for pointing out. I added more actual context and hope it helps. I also added playground links for both examples.

Comment: `return this as Base<string>` looks like you are doing something that doesn't make sense, because not every `this` is a `Base<string>`. What problem are you actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types

Comment: @kaya3 i think it makes sense. Please have a look at the (second) example with my actual context. When creating a `SpecialConfig` instance, the generic `Errors` type is `unknown`, but once the `withValidation` has been called the `Errors` type can be determined by the return type of the passed function.

Comment: @MaciejSikora I already came across this article but unfortunately it doesn't help in my case. The key difference is that in the example of that article the class is not generic, neither the generic type needs to be adapted when return `this`.

Comment: Your example is still unsound, because some other variable could still hold a reference to the same instance, and that variable would not know that the instance's type has changed in-place; the variable's type could still be something else.

Comment: That said, for your use-case you don't need to return `this` at all, because whoever calls your method already has a reference to the object. You can make the return type `asserts this is Base<string>`, and then the caller will have a `Base<string>` after the call because that's how an `asserts` return type works.

Comment: @kaya3 Wow i never saw `asserts this is Base<string>` syntax before, interesting. Is there a good article for this feature? Unfortunately that is not working out well for me because it would completely break the fluent API syntax: `obj.doA().doB().doC()...`. I understand your point that it is unsound, but in my opinion that's a use case. At the beginning you dont know (`unknown`) the type of a generic, but once some function is called (`withValidation`) the type can be inferred. Is there any way to use `asserts .. is ..` syntax and still return `this`? That would be the ideal solution i guess.

Comment: I see; if you accept the risk of violating type-safety then that's up to you, of course. Yes, unfortunately the assertion functions ([docs link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)) won't work with method chaining. Another option is an intersection type, `: this & Base<string>`, I'm not sure whether that will work in your use-case but it's worth a try.

Comment: [Related](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6223)